intlTelInput getNumber() missing dialCode
I initialize the instance like this:
var iti = window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#myNumber"), {
    separateDialCode: true,
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@23.0.11/build/js/utils.js"
});

everything is working fine if I use
iti.getNumber();

But if I do not have access to the original iti instance, I tried:
window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#myNumber")).getNumber();

I get back a number without the dial code (IDD country code)
Borrow codepen sample codes from here
https://codepen.io/sk1511/pen/JjGvPQy

use getNumber method with intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164 as argument, which retrieves full number including country code, try doing:
..
function getValue(){
  var number = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
  alert(number);
}
..

Demo fiddle

In this case, it requires us to know that iti instance in the first place.

I have found the solution. In V23.0.11 it has changed to:
intlTelInput.getInstance(document.querySelector("#myNumber")).getNumber();

